# Can't find variable: Auth0Lock Ionic2 Auth0

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic2, auth0

I was attempting to add Auth0 to my Ionic 2 application and ran into an error saying "Can't find variable: Auth0Lock".

My confusion about this was that the variable was declared, and it was of type "any" so it should have been fine, but when I checked the main.js compiled file, I found that it was not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem I made a simple change to the Auth class which I had gotten from the Auth0 quickstart page, shown here:

```
// app/auth.service.ts

import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
// Configure Auth0
lock = new Auth0Lock('client_id','domain', {});
```

and to fix the issue where Auth0Lock was not being added into the compiled js file (that is to say, it was not being added to the program running on the actual app) I made this change:

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';


@Injectable()
export class Auth {
// Avoid name not found warnings
Auth0Lock: any;

// Configure Auth0
lock = new Auth0Lock('client_id','domain', {});
```

1.) added "import Auth0Lock from 'auth0-lock';

2.) removed *declare var Auth0Lock: any;*

3.) added *Auth0Lock: any;* **inside** the Auth class

that's it! (now don't forget to set up ip address in CORS & etc ;) )